# how take an element that appear when I click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose to have an html page and when I click on one button I read:"

[image]

I need to handle when I click "ok"

that is html code:

```
<button data-bb-handler="confirm" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
```

That is my jquery code:

```
(function() {

        $(document).on('click','button[data-bb-handler="confirm"][type="button"]',function(){
            console.log("MAREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE "+$(this).length);
        });

}());
```

It doesn't work. Anyone can help me? Some other method?

Comment: what do you need exactly? show class after click on "ok" or do something like delete post from database?

Comment: yes i need to delete some elements in db

Comment: can you work with sql query?! like this code: `SELECT teamname FROM usersystem WHERE teamname = '".$teamname."'` | if you can tell me to give an example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/3815/ it is working ?

Comment: @cjmling it is not resolve my problem because I need to get if the user (in a modal confirm) click on the ok button or the other.

Comment: @Ashe That alert mean he clicked the ok button. If you want to detect cancel button then bind an another on click event for that cancel button. Try this https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/3816/

Comment: I think the problem is that your modal pop up events are not attached. You should add a function that will attach the click event after the modal pop up is shown/loaded. If you are using bootstrap (based on your class names I assume you are) you can hook into the `$('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){...attach click event here...});` [see reference](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) scroll to events

Comment: Your code should work, using the on (instead of click) even allows you to catch the click even on dynamically created elements - the only reason I can think of is that the pop up and script are not in the same scope

Comment: @Jamesonthedog how can I do this?

Comment: @Ashe is it possible that the popup and script are not in the same page (iframe)?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of Jquery code should work:

```
$('button[data-bb-handler="confirm"][type="button"]').click(function(){
  console.log("MAREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE "+$(this).length);
});
```

Let me know if it did not work. Check this [Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/pEEXkW)

Comment: check the above link for working code & check if it behaves as expected

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa ur codepen link is something totally different .. wrong link ?

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting to use [Bootbox JS](http://bootboxjs.com/). it is based on Bootstrap layout.

You can achieve that you need as mentioned below

```
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
  // write your code what you need to handle on OK button
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the event *show.bs.modal*:

```js
//
// On modal show
//
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  //
  // attach the click event  for OK button
  //
  $('button[data-bb-handler="cancel"][type="button"]').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log("CANCEL BUTTON PRESSED");
  });

  //
  // attach the click event  for CANCEL button
  //
  $('button[data-bb-handler="confirm"][type="button"]').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log("OK BUTTON PRESSED");
  });
});

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you wish to discard this post?", function () {
    });
  }).trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<button id="myBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
```

This is the bootbox.confirm message. For deatils you may refer to [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/).

When you click on the ok or cancel the dialog dom element is removed from the document.

So you have to use the callback function:

```js
$(document).on('click.bootbox', function(e, result){
  console.log("Pressed "+ result);
});

bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you wish to discard this post?", function(result) {
  $(document).trigger('click.bootbox', result);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```