# how get confirm button value modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose to have an html page and when I click on one button I read:"

[image]

I need to handle when I click "ok" button

that is html code:

```
     <div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
<button type="button" class="bootbox-close-button close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: -10px;">×</button>
<div class="bootbox-body">Are you sure you wish to discard this post?</div></div><div class="modal-footer"><button data-bb-handler="cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button><button data-bb-handler="confirm" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button></div></div>
```

That is my jquery code:

```
(function() {

        $(document).on('click','button[data-bb-handler="confirm"][type="button"]',function(){
            console.log("MAREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE "+$(this).length);
        });

}());
```

It doesn't work. Anyone can help me? Some other method?

Comment: can you share a demo?

Comment: You dont have to add the data-bb-handler attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how take an element that appear when I click a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575318/how-take-an-element-that-appear-when-i-click-a-button)

Answer (score 1):

You can just handle the event directly like this:

```
<button id="confirmBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>

(function() {

   $("#confirmBtn").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log("This " + $(this).length);
   })

}());
```

Comment: except the button doesnt have an `ID`

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATE***

You may use the event *show.bs.modal*:

```js
//
// On modal show
//
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  //
  // attach the click event  for OK button
  //
  $('button[data-bb-handler="cancel"][type="button"]').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log("CANCEL BUTTON PRESSED");
  });

  //
  // attach the click event  for CANCEL button
  //
  $('button[data-bb-handler="confirm"][type="button"]').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log("OK BUTTON PRESSED");
  });
});

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you wish to discard this post?", function () {
    });
  }).trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<button id="myBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
```

This is the bootbox.confirm message. For deatils you may refer to [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/).

When you click on the ok or cancel the dialog dom element is removed from the document.

So you have to use the callback function:

```js
$(document).on('click.bootbox', function(e, result){
  console.log("Pressed "+ result);
});

bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you wish to discard this post?", function(result) {
  $(document).trigger('click.bootbox', result);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know that in your example work but in mine no. Now this is my code: 
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
   
   $(document).on('click', 'button[data-bb-handler="confirm"][type="button"]', function() {
    console.log("OK BUTTON PRESSED");
   });

  });
 });

Comment: also if I use $('button[data-bb-handler="confirm"][type="button"]').on('click', function(e){
    console.log("OK BUTTON PRESSED");
  }); it doesn't work

Comment: @Ashe I use a different event delegation: pay attention to my $(document).ready(function() {.  Moreover, could you check your libraries versions and compare them with my libraries? Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add $(document).ready

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'button[data-bb-handler="confirm"][type="button"]', function() {
    console.log("MAREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE " + $(this).length);
  });
});

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'button[data-bb-handler="confirm"][type="button"]', function() {
    console.log("MAREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE " + $(this).length);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-bb-handler="confirm" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
```

Comment: Maybe you don't understand the problem, I need to handle the click on "ok" when a confirm alert is open. It is not a simple button like you do in this example!

Comment: i think this `(function() {

}());` works same as document ready

Answer (score 0):

I did the same and I'll share my code as an example:

```
$('.delete').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var id = $(this).data('num');
          var action = $(this).data('action');
          if (action=='enable') {
            azione='riattivare';
          }else{
            azione='disabilitare';
          }
          bootbox.confirm("Vuoi "+azione+" il movimento selezionato?", function(result) {
              if (result==true) {
                delete_mov(id,action);
              }else{
                bootbox.alert('Nessuna modifica effettuata');
              }
              //bootbox.alert("Movimento correttamente cancellato");
              //console.log("cancello il record "+id);
          });
        });
```

In my code when you click a `class delete` button it opens a modal to ask for a confirmation (the same as you need to do). Note the callback on `bootbox.confirm`. If you hit ok the result is true else is false. So if in the callback you get `result==true` user hit on ok

Answer (score 0):

I did the same and I'll share my code as an example:

```
$('.delete').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var id = $(this).data('num');
          var action = $(this).data('action');
          if (action=='enable') {
            azione='riattivare';
          }else{
            azione='disabilitare';
          }
          bootbox.confirm("Vuoi "+azione+" il movimento selezionato?", function(result) {
              if (result==true) {
                delete_mov(id,action);
              }else{
                bootbox.alert('Nessuna modifica effettuata');
              }
          });
        });
```

In my code when you click a `class delete` button it opens a modal to ask for a confirmation (the same as you need to do). Note the callback on `bootbox.confirm`. If you hit ok the result is true else is false. So if in the callback you get `result==true` user hit on ok